# Laptop brightness adjustment not working AMD graphics card

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, display-driver, amd-graphics-card

I have a Dell Precision M6600 laptop with an AMD Radeon HD 8950 graphic card running Windows 10. When I use the graphics driver from AMD, computer games work great, but the brightness control does not work on the computer. When I switch to the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter(see screenshot) computer games are unplayable, but the screen brightness adjusts correctly. I am forced to switch between the drivers depending on what I’m doing.

I’m running Radeon Software Crimson Edition version 16.7.3 and I’ve re-downloaded the driver a couple of times to make sure it’s the latest. If I go to Device manager, Generic PnP Monitor is always enabled.

It’s a pain having to switch drivers every few days. How do I get the brightness to adjust correctly with the AMD driver? 
[image: Driver Options]

[image: Generic PnP Monitor is enabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue affects lots of AMD cards and drivers. The fix is as follows.

1. Go to the registry editor (start > regedit)
2. Change both of the following registries to 0

> KMD_EnableBrightnessInterface2
>
> MD_EnableBrightnesslf2

The registry path can vary slightly, but it will be one of the following or something similar. To find they key, I did a search through the registry.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001

3. Reboot.
4. If it still doesn’t work, in Device Manager, disable your video adapter and re-enable. Make sure your PnP monitor is still enabled.

Note: In my case MD_EnableBrightnesslf2 didn’t exist. In this case just changing KMD_EnableBrightnessInterface2 to 0 will fix the problem.

[image: Registry Fix]

Comment: WHOAH. I have an MSI GX60 (1AE, A10-5750m and 7970m) and I always had a working graphics driver OR adjustable brightness. With linux the fix in grub was easy. But with this solution it works again. THANK YOU :)

Comment: Works for Lenovo ideapad S405 (I disabled the discrete graphics in the BIOS). Only KMD_EnableBrightnessInterface2 need to be changed to 0.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this problem, I found a solution. Follow these steps:

1. Run Windows in safe mode
2. Go to Computer Management / Device Manager / Display Adapters / AMD Readon / Driver
3. Uninstall
4. Reboot your PC and it will work

PS: It's better to install an old version for good work