# no brightness control 2019

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card

re [Laptop brightness adjustment not working AMD graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/1123251/laptop-brightness-adjustment-not-working-amd-graphics-card/1123252#1123252)

It looks like you may be on to something there with the regedit but my win7 x64 with the radeon 3200 (old HP laptop) has neither hkey value.  My brightness slider seems stuck at 30 and the f7 f8 toggles do nothing, screen dim.   Have tried "everything."  3 versions of drivers, all that; had same thing happen 2 years ago when reinstalled 7, then stuff fixed a week later somehow.  This time no new updates to be had. (different this time is swapped mobo last week but everything else works fine, just the brightness again.) Something conflicted somewhere but sure seems it should have that enablebrightnessinterface in registry. Help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it *basically* makes sense on its own (currently it doesn’t). Keep the link to the other question as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, since I tried everything else, I flashed the BIOS and that fixed it.  Still no sign of those HKEY KMD_ or MD_ values (enablebrightness etc) in the registry, however.  And I had to flash the bios with a bootable rom dos cd as HP wouldn't let me do it thru win7 or the funpaq method.  Amazing.  Got my brightness slider sliding again, everything bright and cheery.  No ATI catalyst, no extra hotkey support, no new drivers (I had pretty much rolled back, uninstalled, reinstalled, etc a dozen times) just an updated BIOS.